# n-torsion points along a family of elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I was informed of the following geometric picture, and I would appreciate some references and details about it. Consider a family of elliptic curves converging to a self-intersecting rational curve $R$ over $\mathbb{CP}^1$ (so the elliptic curves are fibers over $\mathbb{C}$, and this rational curve $R$ is over $\infty$). Consider the subgroup $S_1\times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for some $n$, where the $n$-torsion points lie on some of these circles, then one of these circles is "stable", as in it will converge to a circle on $R$, while other circles will converge to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ at different speed (the further from the stable circle, the faster?). I have also attached a drawing of the picture, and I would appreciate some texts about this. Is there any way to describe the speed how these circles converge to infinity, maybe using the parameter that describes the family?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what is $S_1\times \Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @reuns I think on each $E$ this is a subgroup, and the n torsion points lie on these circles. I am not sure if this is a known construction or if it has a name, and in fact I would appreciate references on this exactly.

Comment: Ok. Not uninteresting, but then remove the "$n$-torsion" words because this is not a torsion subgroup. The picture is pretty easy on the complex torus side, it gets a bit of headache on the algebraic curve side.

Comment: @reuns Thank you for the advice. I have changed the wording. Can you elaborate in the complex torus' setting?

Comment: According to Hartshorne exercise IV 4.22, any family of elliptic curves $X \to \mathbb C$ which admits a section, is trivial. I.e. $X = E \times \mathbb C$, where $E \subset X$ is any fiber. You need to have a section, if you want to define $n$-torsion points. I don't know how (or if) the trivial family can still degenerate over $\infty$. Otherwise, you might have to exclude a few more points from $\mathbb C$, where fibers could also be singular.